# Pass strongly typed ViewModel value to a Javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

```
<div class="float-l wdth290">
    @Html.DropDownGroupListFor(m => m.GroupId,
                               Model.GroupedTypeOptions,
                               new
                               {
                                   name = "ddlGroupName",
                                   id = "ddlGroupName",
                                   @onchange = "javascript:OnDropDownChangeLoadGroup(this.value,'');"
                               })
</div>
```

I have the sample DropDownGroupListFor above. On its onchange, i want to call OnDropDownChangeLoadGroup function and also pass two parameters values (this.value) and

> m => m.GroupId

but i can't figure how to pass that as the second parameter.

Comment: I don't know how to write it in this language (.Net?) but what you can do is set the value of each dowpdownlist's item with a json (ow array) with both values and the OnDropDownChangeLoadGroup handle the value (parse the json or the array).

Comment: You are better off writing the Javascript in `<script></script>` tags then binding to the element that this HTML Helper method will create. What you have to remember is that Razor syntax is compiled into HTML before being sent to the client, so the client will render the pure HTML.

Comment: The value of `GroupId` **is** the value of the selected option (`this.value`) - they are the same. What are you actually trying to do here? Note also `name = "ddlGroupName"` is pointless (check the html generated - and fortunately it does not work or you would lose all model binding) and why change the `id` from `GroupId` to `ddlGroupName`?

Answer (score 0):

Well `m => m.GroupId` sets the `name` and `id` of the `select` tag. Since you are already hardcoding it, you might as well hardcode the call too.

```
@onchange = "javascript:OnDropDownChangeLoadGroup(this.value, 'ddlGroupName');"
```

If you hadn't set the name and id the default would have simply been `GroupId`.